# Detect @ in the starting of the word and add a span around the word in reactjs

Tags: css, reactjs, css-selectors

I would like to detect the `@` character in the word and add a span around the word My output is in the following format:

```
<p class="comments">Where is @james? I hope him and @elaine are okay.</p>
```

I would like it to become:

```
<p class="comments">Where is <span>@james</span>? I hope him and <span>@elaine</span> are okay.</p>
```

The point of me doing this is that I would like to style the names. I'm looking for `reactjs` solution but if there's any CSS methods, that would be okay too.

Comment: There is no way, as far as I am aware, for CSS to select by text content, nor for it to insert markup around its target.  I believe you will require a JavaScript solution to this problem.

Comment: Yes and hence, I'm asking for reactjs solution. I'll edit my ending line.

Answer (score 3):

You can split comment/text into an array with regrexp as [text, user, etc...] and then reconstruct it with map, while iterating over array you can check if a string starts with '@' if so then wrap string in span tag

```
import React from 'react';

export default ({ comment = 'random text @username more random  @username2 text asdsad'}) => {
  function pipeDecorateUsername(text) {
    // took pattern from Drew Reese answer
    const regexpPattern = /(@[a-z0-9\-\_]*)/gi;
    // split text into components/strings as [text..., username, etc...]
    const textComponents = text.split(regexpPattern)
    return (
        <>
          {textComponents.map(component => {
            /**
             * wrap username in span
             */
            if(component[0] === '@') {
                return (
                  <span style={{color: 'green'}}>{component}</span>
                )
            }
            else {
              return component;
            }
          })}

        </>
      )
  }
  return (
    <div>
      {pipeDecorateUsername(comment)}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thank you but it has to be dynamic as the sentences would change.

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex `/(@[a-z0-9]*)/gi` to match, and include, the `@` and word, and string::replace to wrap with a span.

Here, `/(@[a-z0-9]*)/gi` does a global, case-insensitive search for words that *only* contain the letters a through z and digits, but you can adjust that if the words you want to wrap can include other characters.

`string.replace(regex, '<span>$1</span>')` is invoking the regex to search for and replace found captured matches (i.e. the `$1` in the span).

```js
const regex = /(@[a-z0-9]*)/gi;

const string = 'Where is @james? I hope him and @elaine are okay.';

console.log(string.replace(regex, '<span>$1</span>'));
```

This, of course, only gives you a string with `"<span>"` literal in it, so to *actually* render this back as html you can use react [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml), so you can extract the above into a utility function

```
const formatAts = text => {
  const regex = /(@[a-z0-9]*)/gi;
  return text.replace(regex, '<span>$1</span>');
}
```

and use in JSX

```
<p
  class="comments"
  dangerouslySetInnerHTML={
    formatAts('Where is @james? I hope him and @elaine are okay.')
  }
/>
```